# Issue with true division with Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division

Suppose you have this array:

```
In [29]: a = array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [14, 28, 42, 56, 70], [18, 36, 54, 72, 90]])

Out[30]: a
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [14, 28, 42, 56, 70],
       [18, 36, 54, 72, 90]])
```

Now divide the third row by the first one (using from **future** import division)

```
In [32]: a[0]/a[2]
Out[32]: array([ 0.55555556,  0.55555556,  0.55555556,  0.55555556,  0.55555556])
```

Now do the same with each row in a loop:

```
In [33]: for i in range(3):
            print a[i]/a[2]   
[ 0.55555556  0.55555556  0.55555556  0.55555556  0.55555556]
[ 0.77777778  0.77777778  0.77777778  0.77777778  0.77777778]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Everything looks right. But now, assign the first array a[i]/a[2] to a[i]:

```
In [35]: for i in range(3):
            a[i]/=a[2]
   ....:     

In [36]: a
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Alright, no problem. Turns out [this is by design](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2061). Instead, we should do:

```
In [38]: for i in range(3):
            a[i] = a[i]/a[2]
   ....:     

In [39]: a
Out[39]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But that doesn't work. Why and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast the whole array to a `float` array first:

```
a = a.astype('float')
a /= a[2]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I thought about that but I was wondering about a solution involving the division since it should work as a[i] = a[i]/a[2]

Comment: In case it's not obvious, this creates a new array.  There is no way (that I know of) to do it that modifies the old array in place and changes the type.

Comment: It's not possible to do in general since the old and new types may have different sizes, or the old array might be a view into some other array that shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @nneonneo -- true -- sort of.  From a python API perspective, that doesn't matter.  `ndarray` is a wrapper around a c-array (data).  In principle, you could just move the pointer that your ndarray has to a new block of data and from a python perspective, you did the operation "in place".  e.g. `a = array(...); b = a; a.magic_type_convert(float); b.dtype is a.dtype #true`.  But, I don't know if that operation exists.  And provided that `views` are holding the same reference to the data (and I think they are), that would work too.

Comment: @mgilson Actually, I hadn't considered that. However, numpy arrays are still mutable c = array([1]); id(c) returns 32610992. Then c[0] = 2 changes the array to array([2]) and id(c) still returns 32610992, so I thought it could be doing the same by row.

Comment: @RobertSmith -- Yes, I'm not saying the arrays aren't immutable.  You can change the data inside (otherwise they won't be very useful).  But, you can't change the *type* of the data inside.  If `c` starts off holding `int`s, it will always hold `int`s no matter what you put on the RHS of the equation.

Comment: Right. Interesting. I need to get used to numpy arrays :-) Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

"Why doesn't this work" -- The reason it doesn't work is because numpy arrays have a datatype when they're created.  Any attempt to put a different type into that array will be cast to the appropriate type.  In other words, when you try to put a float into your integer array, numpy casts the float to an int.  The reasoning behind this is because numpy arrays are designed to be a homogonous type in order for them to have optimal performance.  Put another way, they're implemented as arrays in C.  And in C, you can't have an array where 1 element is a `float` and the next is an `int`.  (You can have `struct`s which behave like that, but they're not arrays).

Another solution (in addition to the one proposed by @nneonneo) is to specify the array as a float array from the beginning:

```
a = array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [14, 28, 42, 56, 70], [18, 36, 54, 72, 90]], dtype=float)
```

Comment: Right. Yes, you're absolutely right as a.dtype returns dtype('int64') Then once an array is created, unless explicitly changed, it keeps its data type. Is that it?

Comment: @RobertSmith -- It keeps it's data type no matter what.  You *can't* explicitly change the data type.  Doing `a.astype(float)` actually creates a *new* ndarray which is of type `float`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the division that's the issue it's the assignment, ie `a[i] = ...` (which is also used behind the scene when you do `a /= ...`). Try this:

```
>>> a = np.zeros(3, dtype='uint8')
>>> a[:] = [2, -3, 5.9]
>>> print a
[  2 253   5]
```

When you do `intarray[i] = floatarray[i]` numpy has to truncate the floating point values to get them to fit into `intarray`.