# Python loop/proportion does not work: [0,0...] not understandeable

Tags: python

I have written following Python function. Observed was calculated earlier and has following values:

```
observed= [17694753, 16492579, 13668937, 15684150, 13338829, 10223524, 13641400]

#Calculate the proportion of each day
proportions=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
for i in np.arange(7):
    print(observed[i])
    print("sum ", sum(observed))
    proportions[i]=observed[i]/sum(observed)

print(proportions)
```

This is the output:

```
17694753
16492579
13668937
15684150
13338829
10223524
13641400

sum 100744172
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Logically, I would expect a value close to 1/7 for each value within proportions so I do not understand why it is [0 0 0 0 0 0 0].

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You appear to be using Python 2, where `/` is floored division if both arguments are `int`s.

Comment: You are providing integers so Python is doing integer division, and the divisor is greater than all the dividends, so you will always get results 0

Comment: The `proportions` NumPy  array has integer dtype, so when you assign a floating-point value to it, that floating-point value is truncated before being stored. Create `proportions` with dtype `float` instead, e.g., with `proportions = np.zeros(7, dtype=float)`.

Comment: @chepner: Python 2 seems unlikely here: under Python 2, `print("sum ", sum(observed))` would be printing a tuple (at least, in the absence of  any `__future__` imports).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with true division with Numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985503/issue-with-true-division-with-numpy-arrays)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point.

Comment: Of course, the whole thing is moot if you just write `proportions = np.array(observed)/sum(observed)`. (I don't know `numpy` well enough to know if there's already a method for normalizing an array in this fashion.)

Answer (score 1):

NumPy includes a base type for its arrays.  Since you assigned integers, you have an `int` array.  You're then assigning float values to `int` locations; the values are truncated.  The easiest repair is to the original typing:

```
proportions = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

Output:

```
17694753
sum  100744172
16492579
sum  100744172
13668937
sum  100744172
15684150
sum  100744172
13338829
sum  100744172
10223524
sum  100744172
13641400
sum  100744172
[0.17564046 0.16370752 0.13567968 0.15568295 0.13240298 0.10148005
 0.13540634]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating over the elements of `observed` explicitly, you can compute the sum and divide each element of a new array by that sum.

```
>>> observed= [17694753, 16492579, 13668937, 15684150, 13338829, 10223524, 13641400]
>>> np.array(observed)/sum(observed)
array([0.17564046, 0.16370752, 0.13567968, 0.15568295, 0.13240298,
       0.10148005, 0.13540634])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( without numpy though ) -

```
proportions = [ val/sum(observed) for val in observed ]
proportions
[0.17564046285476445, 0.1637075244412153, 0.13567967981314094, 0.15568295106936805, 0.13240298406542067, 0.10148005385363632, 0.13540634390245423]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy was assigned as int array based on initialisation and you are putting float on that int array.

```
import numpy as np
observed= [17694753, 16492579, 13668937, 15684150, 13338829, 10223524, 13641400]

#Calculate the proportion of each day
proportions = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
for i in range(7):
    print(observed[i])
    sum_obserbed = sum(observed)
    print( "Sum " , sum_obserbed)
    proportions[i] = observed[i])/sum(observed)

print(proportions)
```

Answer:

```
[0.17564046 0.16370752 0.13567968 0.15568295 0.13240298 0.10148005
0.13540634]
```